# How do you make a custom .onion link?

Tags: onion-services, private-key

I read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29772/how-do-you-get-a-specific-onion-address-for-your-hidden-service) one but didn't explain how to plug in your "private_key" properly. I have a "private_key" but I can't get it into the /var/lib/tor/hidden_service without changing the permissions and that mess's things up

Comment: Well I think I fixed it using nautilus-gksu but now tor is a broken package. If you wanna help we with that just look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/775387/how-to-remove-a-broken-package

Comment: put the key files in a folder you're specifying for your HS. It will "suck the keys in" and it will work. Create a folder if it's missing